# R: index to a draframe row by index and column name gives all levels

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using foor loop to get cell values of a dataframe

```
  for(k in 1:nrow(myDF)){
    for(h in names(myDF[k,])){
           a<-myDF[k,][["colname"]]
           print(a)
    }   
  }
```

It gives the desired value with all level. you can see the first value is the actual value in the desired cell but below that it gives all the level. What is the reason for this behavior and how to avoid getting all levels.

Result

```
[1] 1800-01-01
375 Levels: 1/10/2018 1/11/2018 1/12/2018 1/13/2018 1/15/2018 1/16/2018 1/16/2019 1/17/2018 1/17/2019 1/18/2018 1/19/2018 1/20/2018 1/21/2019 1/22/2018 1/22/2019 ... 9/9/2018
[1] 1800-01-01
375 Levels: 1/10/2018 1/11/2018 1/12/2018 1/13/2018 1/15/2018 1/16/2018 1/16/2019 1/17/2018 1/17/2019 1/18/2018 1/19/2018 1/20/2018 1/21/2019 1/22/2018 1/22/2019 ... 9/9/2018
[1] 1800-01-01
375 Levels: 1/10/2018 1/11/2018 1/12/2018 1/13/2018 1/15/2018 1/16/2018 1/16/2019 1/17/2018 1/17/2019 1/18/2018 1/19/2018 1/20/2018 1/21/2019 1/22/2018 1/22/2019 ... 9/9/2018
[1] 1800-01-01
375 Levels: 1/10/2018 1/11/2018 1/12/2018 1/13/2018 1/15/2018 1/16/2018 1/16/2019 1/17/2018 1/17/2019 1/18/2018 1/19/2018 1/20/2018 1/21/2019 1/22/2018 1/22/2019 ... 9/9/2018
[1] 1800-01-01
375 Levels: 1/10/2018 1/11/2018 1/12/2018 1/13/2018 1/15/2018 1/16/2018 1/16/2019 1/17/2018 1/17/2019 1/18/2018 1/19/2018 1/20/2018 1/21/2019 1/22/2018 1/22/2019 ... 9/9/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of when using `print` on factors. use `max.level = 0` to remove it from printing.

```
z <- data.frame(a = as.factor(c(4,3,2,1)))

print(z[1,])

#output
[1] 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4

print(z[1,], max.levels = 0)

#output
[1] 4
```